# I am unsure of how to follow the instructions

Tags: json

var Mary = '{ "height":1.9, "age":36, "eyeColor":"brown"}';

// use JSON.parse() to create an object 'objectMary':
var objectMary = JSON.parse(Mary);

Instructions:
I need to add an additional line after the existing code to log the value of Mary's age to the console.

What does this mean? How would I do this?

Comment: Additional line where ? In the code ? Can you comment the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to access Mary's age from the json.

```
var Mary = '{ "height":1.9, "age":36, "eyeColor":"brown"}';
var objectMary = JSON.parse(Mary);
```

Here, `objectMary` has the parsed json object and you can directly access properties from it like `objectMary.age`, `objectMary.height`, etc.

If you are trying this code out in `javascript` then you could log Mary's age as

```js
var Mary = '{ "height":1.9, "age":36, "eyeColor":"brown"}';
var objectMary = JSON.parse(Mary);
console.log(objectMary.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `console.log(objectMary.age);` in your existing code.

**DEMO**

```js
var Mary = '{ "height":1.9, "age":36, "eyeColor":"brown"}';
var objectMary = JSON.parse(Mary);
console.log(objectMary.age);
```